# Ошибка записи Date в Sharedpreferences

Tags: android, android-shared-preferences

Пытаюсь записать текущую дату при клике на кнопку, чтобы потом эту дату считать из Sharedpreferences и вывести на экран в TextView, но программа у меня сразу вылетает. вот стандартный код (как везде предлагают):

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref;
Date ddd;
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        sharedPref = getPreferences(MODE_APPEND);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putLong("date", ddd.getTime());
        editor.commit();
}});

//считывание
sharedPref = getPreferences(MODE_APPEND);
long stime = sharedPref.getLong("date", 0L);
textView.setText("clik "+stime);
```

вот красный лог:

```
2011-2011/com.example.proga1 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.proga1, PID: 2011
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.proga1.MainActivity$4.onClick(MainActivity.java:268)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: а что у вас в строке 268? Да и что-то я не вижу инициализации `ddd`. Кажется мне, что если перед `editor.putLong("date", ddd.getTime());` добавить `ddd = new Date();` то все заработает)) Ну или заменить `editor.putLong("date", ddd.getTime());` на `editor.putLong("date", new Date().getTime());` если у вас `ddd` Нигде больше не используется

Comment: Таки да - без указание строки, на коей ошибка возникает вопрос превращается в конкурс экстрасенсов.

Comment: строка 268 как раз и есть "editor.putLong("date", ddd.getTime());", только здесь я над button1 в самом верху показал инициализацию(как раз для вас, жаль что не заметили) - "Date ddd;", только в реале у меня инициализация идет в самом начале после определения класса.

Comment: проблема была в отсутствии ddd = new Date(); Так что комментарий   PhoEn-X можно перенести в ответ

Comment: @Hellraiser, тогда оформлю как ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отсутствует инициализация `Date ddd;` Достаточно добавить `ddd = new Date();` перед `editor.putLong("date", ddd.getTime());`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте стандартные преференсы:

```
sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
```

вместо ваших

> sharedPref = getPreferences(MODE_APPEND);